# Getting specific folder path

Tags: file, recursion, directory

In a random set of nested folders and files, I need to get all folder paths where a particular child folder' name is say "x".

For example, in following structure, I need the program to return back only `a\c\e\x` :

[image]

Please see that there can be any level of nesting and any folder structure.

**UPDATE**:
I have been able to write a basic program to achieve what I wanted. However, it fails when in my previous diagram there is a directory 'dir x' under 'dir d'. So the program returns a\c\e\x and d\x. Can you help make that fix?

public class Zombie {

```
String folderName= new String();
ArrayList folderList= new ArrayList(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path;
    try {
        path = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        Zombie zombie= new Zombie();
        getFilePaths(new File(path).listFiles(), zombie);


        Iterator itr = zombie.folderList.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
            System.out.println(itr.next());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void getFilePaths(File[] fileList, Zombie zombie) {
    for (int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++) {
        File file= fileList[i];
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (containsDesiredFolder(file)) {
                zombie.folderList.add(zombie.folderName+ "\\" + file.getName());
                zombie.folderName="";
            } else {
                if (containsFoldersNotFiles(file)) {
                    zombie.folderName= zombie.folderName + "\\" + file.getName();
                    getFilePaths(file.listFiles(), zombie);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}   

public static boolean containsFoldersNotFiles(File file) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (file.isFile()) return false;

    File[] dummyList = file.listFiles();

    //no file or folder present
    if (dummyList == null)
        return flag;

    for (int i = 0; i < dummyList.length; i++) {
        File dummyFile = dummyList[i];
        if (dummyFile.isDirectory() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

public static boolean containsDesiredFolder(File file) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (file.isFile()) return false;
    File[] dummyList = file.listFiles();

    if (dummyList == null)
        return flag;

    for (int i = 0; i < dummyList.length; i++) {
        File dummyFile = dummyList[i];
        if (dummyFile.isDirectory() && dummyFile.getName().equals("dirx")) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

}

Comment: that depends mainly on the datastructure used to hold the files and folders , what is the datastructure used here ?

Answer (score 0):

1. take seed folder, append its name in folder_list variable of type string.
2. if seed folder is x and its child node add folder_list to global folder_array.
3. traverse all folder of seed folder. while passing folder_list, and passing every child folder as seed folder repeat from 1.

PS: this would pretty much do.